# Доступ к элементу DOM по части его идентификатора

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

В ид элемента может быть указан ид записи, или этот пункт может быть пустым

т.е.

```
id = "12|123|23" или id = "12||23"
```

т.е. хочу получить

```
document.getElementById(id) где знаю только 1 и 3 элемент
```

Comment: Там всегда будут три элемента?

Comment: да число элементов известно. но прелесть в том что 2й элемент я не знаю, но мне нужно использовать (сделать неактивным) элемент с этим ид

Comment: т.е. было `id = "12|123|23"`, стало `id = "12||23"` и вам теперь надо скрыть элемент с `id=123`?

Comment: из строки я получаю 1 и 3 элемент (1 - ид столбца, 3 - ид строки). так вот изменив 1 элемент я могу обратиться к столбцу этой же строки. но 2 элемент - ид записи может быть либо пустым (записи нет), или может быть не пустым

Comment: т.е. однозначно обратиться к элементу id=12|/*preg_match(*)*/|23

Comment: Так не выйдет. Собираете все элементы страницы в массив через `document.getElementsByTagName('*')` и потом в цикле проверяете у каждого элемента его id через регулярное выражение или `split` и сравнение.

Comment: угу типа `console.log("1|||4".split("|"))` или `console.log(/(\d)/g.exec("1|2|3|4"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// Выбираем все элементы, у которых есть известные нам 1 и 3 id
// Не забываем экранировать знак pipe. На всякий случай
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="12\\|"][id$="\\|23"]');
var elementsToHide = [];
var result = document.querySelector('#result');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  // Поскольку в выборке элементы, где как минимум 2 символа pipe в id
  // Мы можем спокойно после split обратиться ко второму элементу
  var hideMe = elements[i].id.split('|')[1];

  // Если второй id не пустой, сохраняем его в результирующий массив.
  if (hideMe) {
    elementsToHide.push(hideMe);
  }
}

result.innerText = elementsToHide.join(', ');
```

```html
<div id="12|123|23"></div>
<div id="12|45|23"></div>
<div id="12||23"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Конечно же, вместо сохранения в массив `ID` искомых элементов, вы можете сохранять туда сами элементы, или же сразу их прятать.

Селектор `[id^="12\\|"][id$="\\|23"]` выбирает элементы, у которых `id` одновременно начинается с `12|` и заканчивается на `|23`.

Comment: А зачем экранировать "|"?

Comment: Потому что этот символ не входит в список разрешенных для использования без экранирования в идентификаторах согласно спецификации: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier . Вот только мне надо было экранировать этот символ с помощью двух слешей. Исправил.

Comment: Кстати про экранирование - по ссылке говорится про идентификаторы, но ведь в коде используется селектор по значению атрибута.

Comment: Ё-мое! Вы правы. Тем не менее, этот знак используется как часть правила селектора `|=`  и для отделения namespace от имени элемента `namespace|element:hover`. Я бы все-таки его экранировал. Тем более, проблемы раньше с ним были: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306252/jquery-selector-doesnt-accept-pipe-character

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен один (первый) элемент:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('[id^="12|"][id$="|23"]'))
```

```html
<div id="12|444|23"></div>
```

Если элементов несколько:

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[id^="12|"][id$="|23"]'))
```

```html
<div id="12|123|23"></div>
<div id="12|45|23"></div>
<div id="12||23"></div>
```

Comment: А в чем разница с моим ответом?

Comment: @VenZell, просто мне было лень его читать... Думал, там проход по всем элементам с id и проверка. Посмотрел внимательнее - получается ни в чём, только мой короче. Держи плюсик.